# Microsoft custom speech - human labeled transcription

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When I train a model using sentences in German.
I found that normalized words are different from my train data.

Following is example.

```
augenschmerzen:augenschmerz
karzinom:carcinom
koloskopie:coloskopie
inkontinenz:inkontinent
inkontinenz:inkontinent
malta:malad
media:medis
media gerichtet:medis gerichtet
orthopädie:orthopädin
urologe:urologin
```

Some of them are just differences between females and male but some of them are totally different from my intention.

Q1) What is the background of those changes? any document about the rule of that chan?

Q2) Can I have an option to train with original data without those changes?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-improve-accuracy#accuracy-in-different-scenarios) to know about "**Accuracy in different scenarios**".
[image]

You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-evaluate-data#resolve-errors-and-improve-wer) about "**resolve errors and improve WER**".

You can also [improve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-improve-accuracy#improve-model-recognition) the accuracy by adding training data in Custom Speech portal.